# Are empty HTML data attributes valid?

Tags: html, custom-data-attribute

I'd like to write a simple jQuery plugin that displays inline modals under specified elements. My idea is for the script to auto-init based on data attributes specified on elements.

A very basic example:

```
<p data-modal-target>Hover over me for an inline modal!</p>
<div data-modal-content data-modal-align="right" data-modal-trigger="hover" data-modal-offset="10px"><!-- any desired syntax can go here --></div>
```

I'm just wondering if `data-modal-target` in the above example is valid, or does it have to be `data-modal-target="true"`? I don't care about anything crappier than IE9 etc, my only requirement is that it be valid HTML.

Comment: I couldn't find where custom data attributes require a value or not; and am still unsure whether to omit the value, or just include it to be safe. The W3C spec is confusing (no surprise). I think it may depend on the script using the values. (comment example continued below, due to length limit).

Comment: e.g., I'm using a plug-in that has custom data attributes with default values: some strings, some booleans (leading me to look for this question). The boolean data has a mix of whether the default is true or false; it's doing the checking to see if it exists or has a value. It's checking if value is either true or empty (for true), or false. But the check for empty is explicit in the code; it's not "built-in". And, it's not checking for the attribute name, like data-abc="data-abc" as a boolean attribute requires; this causes an error.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

**Valid, but they aren't boolean.**

[Custom data attributes specification](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#custom-data-attribute) doesn't mention any changes to empty attributes handling, so the [general rules about empty attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attr-empty) apply here:

> Certain attributes may be specified by providing just the attribute name, with no value.
>
> In the following example, the `disabled` attribute is given with the empty attribute syntax:
>
> ```
> <input disabled>
> ```
>
> Note that empty attribute syntax is exactly equivalent to specifying the empty string as the value for the attribute, as in the following example.
>
> ```
> <input disabled="">
> ```

So you are allowed to use empty custom data attributes, but special handling is needed to use them as boolean.

When you are accessing an empty attribute, its value is `""`. Since it's a falsy value, you can't just use `if (element.dataset.myattr)` to check whether an attribute is present.

You should use `element.hasAttribute('myattr')` or `if (element.dataset.myattr !== undefined)` instead.

---

Lloyd's answer is wrong. He mentions link to boolean attributes microsyntax, but `data-*` attributes are not specified as boolean in the spec.

Comment: "Note that empty attribute syntax is exactly equivalent to specifying the empty string as the value for the attribute, as in the following example." is exactly what I was searching for. Specifically, jQuery's `scriptAttrs` setting doesn't like a plain `defer` value, but a `defer: ""` should do the trick. Thanks!

Comment: If You want to obtain a Boolean property onto HTMLElement You can define a custom getter using hasAttribute. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Comment: element.hasAttribute('data-myattr')

Answer (score 119):

Yes, perfectly valid. In your case, `data-modal-target` would represent a boolean attribute:

> #### [2.4.2 Boolean attributes](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes)
>
> The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true
> value, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the link, I usually don't have the patience to wade through w3.org :)

Comment: oh, me neither - i just happened to know this from regular use of the HTML5 audio element which uses a boolean attribute (`controls`)

Comment: I don't know omitting the value "turns it into" a boolean attribute - it seems that the boolean attributes aren't arbitrary; I think there's a list of them. Maybe it doesn't matter if it's treated as a boolean or custom data by the browser/script; but maybe it depends on the script reading it.

Comment: I believe this has changed.  Certainly the example I am using in my code is not being treated as a boolean but rather as an empty string. So, testing `if ($('p').data('modal-target'))` won't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864999/can-i-use-html5-data-attributes-as-boolean-attributes.

Comment: looks like this is not true `element.dataset.modalTarget` would produce empty string which is falsy (Chrome 32)
same result with jQuery

Comment: How would you determine if data-modal-target exists using jQuery? The value is "" which is a falsy

Comment: This seems to be a misinterpretation of the spec. The section you link to describes Boolean attributes, but does not say if custom data attributes *can* be Boolean attributes.

Comment: the link no longer links to the correct place - this is the section on boolean attributes now https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes

Comment: fixed, thanks @PeterPerháč

Comment: Be aware that this response is wrong. `data-modal-target` without an assigned value is not a boolean value, but - as @user:3075942 said - represents the empty string, and `element.dataset.modalTarget === true` evaluates to `false`.
It _can_ be used as a boolean attribute, though, by interpreting the existence of that attribute as `true`, but this is not the same as "representing a boolean attribute".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is valid syntax to omit value for a custom data attribute.

"Attributes can be specified in four different ways:

Empty attribute syntax
Just the attribute name. The value is implicitly the empty string.
[...]"
https://developers.whatwg.org/syntax.html#attributes-0

Comment: It also says just before "Attributes have a name and a value." It doesn't say "Attributes have a name and an OPTIONAL value."

Comment: The value is not optional:   "The value is implicitly the empty string."

Answer (score 1):

On one hand, it passes the validator 16.5.7 https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>a</title>
</head>
<body data-asdf>
</body>
</html>
```

On the other, HTML5 does not say in the specification of `data-` attributes that they are boolean: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#custom-data-attribute while it says that very clearly for other boolean attributes like `checked` https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-checked