# Set attribute without value

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, attr

How do I set a data attribute without adding a value in jQuery? I want this:

```
<body data-body>
```

I tried:

```
$('body').attr('data-body'); // this is a getter, not working
$('body').attr('data-body', null); // not adding anything
```

Everything else seems to add the second arguments as a string. Is it possible to just set an attribute without value?

Comment: Why do you need `data-body` vs. `data-body=""`?

Comment: At least if you want to use XHTML, you shouldn't do that since [attribute minimization](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.5) is not allowed.

Comment: I don’t use XHTML, I use HTML5

Comment: I'm curious to know why you need to set a new data attribute from the client side. Why not use a property?

Comment: @user1689607 because I’m saving the generated HTML as a string and need to do a reverse lookup later on.

Comment: @ExplosionPills One example is the `required` attribute for HTML5 form validation. I'm sure there are many other valid use cases.

Comment: Another use which I am currently looking for is setting the itemscope Microdata for google search engine, e.g. `<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">`

Comment: Empty `data-` attributes are not necessarily valid: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729080/are-empty-html5-data-attributes-valid

Answer (score 305, accepted):

The `attr()` function is also a setter function. You can just pass it an empty string.

```
$('body').attr('data-body','');
```

An empty string will simply create the attribute with no value.

```
<body data-body>
```

> Reference - http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-value
>
> attr( attributeName , value  )

Comment: +1, but the OP knows it's a setter. The fact that passing an empty string works but `null` does not is somewhat surprising.

Comment: [Javasctipt has some weird behaviors](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXEgk1Hdze0). Knowing where these oddities happen will take out the element of surprize :P

Comment: Note: This doesn't work with jQuery 1.7.2 (I know that's not the latest version) but using `$(el).prop('data-body', true)` worked for me where `$(el).attr('data-body', '')` ended up setting data-body="data-body" for me.

Comment: @PatrickO'Doherty `$(el).prop('data-body', true)` does not work for me.  `attr()` does work but it also adds an empty string as value of the attribute I want to add.

Comment: and how does one remove the empty attribute?

Comment: @Andrew I believe that you're looking for the [removeAttr/prop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626517/remove-disabled-attribute-using-jquery?noredirect=1&lq=1) functions. It depends which attribute you're trying to remove.

Answer (score 67):

Perhaps try:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
body.setAttribute("data-body","");
```

Comment: Only this solution worked for me `var btn = $(this).get(0);
                        btn.setAttribute("disabled","");`

Comment: After messing around with .attr and .prop, like suggested in all the other solutions and comments here, I finally found that going back (or at least 
"half-way" back) to native JS, did the trick, like suggested in the comment above... Cheers for that!

Comment: `body.setAttribute("data-body","");` this will set 'false' value of my attribute, how can I set ""(empty) value of an attribute?

Answer (score 28):

The **accepted answer doesn't** create a name-only attribute anymore (as of September 2017).

You should use JQuery [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method to create name-only attributes.

```
$(body).prop('data-body', true)
```

Comment: Actually, I appear to be adding "value='true'" to my select option, instead of just "value".  Ugh.

Comment: i was wondering how the accepted answer did not contain this solution! it's the cleanest way using jquery.

Comment: Doesn't work in select dropdown options, in Chrome  unfortunately

Answer (score 19):

You can do it without jQuery!

Example:

```js
document.querySelector('button').setAttribute('disabled', '');
```

```html
<button>My disabled button!</button>
```

> *To set the value of a Boolean attribute, such as disabled, you can specify any value. An empty string or the name of the attribute are recommended values. All that matters is that if the attribute is present at all, regardless of its actual value, its value is considered to be true. The absence of the attribute means its value is false. By setting the value of the disabled attribute to the empty string (""), we are setting disabled to true, which results in the button being disabled.*
>
> From [MDN Element.setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

Comment: jQuery is too flakey in this regard. Best to do in javascript lest you drive yourself crazy every time jquery or browsers change. This goes for all these buggy client frameworks.

Answer (score 15):

Not sure if this is really beneficial or why I prefer this style but what I do (in vanilla js) is:

```js
// Add
document.querySelector('#selector')
    .toggleAttribute('data-something', true);

// Remove
document.querySelector('#selector')
    .toggleAttribute('data-something', false);

// Toggle
document.querySelector('#selector')
    .toggleAttribute('data-something');
```

This may add the attribute in all lowercase without a value or remove it if it already exists on the element.

---

> #### Syntax...
>
> `toggleAttribute(name, force)`
>
> #### Parameters...
>
> - `force` *Optional*
>
> A boolean value which has the following effects:
>
> if not specified at all, the toggleAttribute method "toggles" the
> attribute named name — removing it if it is present, or else adding it
> if it is not present if true, the toggleAttribute method adds an
> attribute named name if false, the toggleAttribute method removes the
> attribute named name

Source: [toggleAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/toggleAttribute)

Comment: I still havent found a solution. In my project I still get data-something="" when using this approach.

Comment: This is the only solution that is working otherwise, everything else is throwing this:
Error: <element> attribute width: Unexpected end of attribute. Expected length, "".

Answer (score 5):

simply try this, it will definately work....

`document.querySelector("audio").setAttribute("autoplay", "");`

this will showed like below code;-

```
<audio autoplay>

</audio>
```

if you wrote like,

`$("audio").attr("autoplay", "");`

then, this will showed like below code;-

```
<audio autoplay="autoplay">

</audio>
```

Answer (score 4):

We have a lot of good answers here.

But, you have to see that **inside Firefox** it gives you `data-body=""` and **inside Chrome** it gives you `data-body` only.