# use webkit-playsinline in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, video

How do I use webkit-playsinline in javascript instead of in html5 video tag? I want to use it just like using video tag control/autoplay attribute in javascript or if you guys have any other method that is working? I'm working on a PhoneGap iOS app that stream video.

Below is some approach that I have tried but none are working:

> videoPlayer.WebKitPlaysInline = "webkit-playsinline";
>   videoPlayer.WebKitPlaysInline = "WebKitPlaysInline";
>   videoPlayer.webkit-playsinline = "webkit-playsinline";
>   videoPlayer.WebKitPlaysInline = "true";
>   videoPlayer.WebKitPlaysInline = true;
>   videoPlayer.webkit-playsinline = "true";
>   videoPlayer.webkit-playsinline = true;

My current code(js):

```
function loadPlayer() {
    var videoPlayer = document.createElement('video');
videoPlayer.controls = "controls";
    videoPlayer.autoplay = "autoplay";
    videoPlayer.WebKitPlaysInline = true;
    document.getElementById("vidPlayer").appendChild(videoPlayer);
    nextChannel();
}
```

My current code(html):

```
<body onload="loadPlayer(document.getElementById('vidPlayer'));"><!-- load js function -->

<li><span class="ind_player"><div id="vidPlayer"></div></span></li><!-- video element creat here -->
```

Any helps are much appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: adding `webkit-playsinline` to the `<video>` tag doesn't work on mobile safari or chrome on iPhone. Have you figured out how to make this work?

Answer (score 7):

You can do this without jQuery:

```
var videoElement = document.createElement( 'video' );
videoElement.setAttribute('webkit-playsinline', 'webkit-playsinline');
```

You have to activate this functionality in your iOs application's WebView :

```
webview.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true;
```

You can check this post for more details:

[HTML5 inline video on iPhone vs iPad/Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699552/html5-inline-video-on-iphone-vs-ipad-browser)

Comment: Starting iOS10, the name of the attribute changed from `'webkit-playsinline'` to `'playsinline'`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to attach it to the video element and set it as video's attribute

such as :

```
<video class="" poster="" webkit-playsinline>
    <source src="" type="video/ogg" preload="auto">
    <source src="" type="video/mp4" preload="auto">                
</video>
```

so you could do (with jQuery) :

```
$('video').attr('webkit-playsinline', '');
```

Comment: `.attr` called with only one parameter is a getter, you need to specify the value to make it a setter. just pass an empty string then: `$('video').attr('webkit-playsinline', '')`. 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/13159270/1052033

Comment: Our UIWebView iOS app needed the "controls" attribute before it allowed playing inline.

Comment: Thanks! This is a life saver. Especially if one is trying to make autoplay vids via TinyMCE, as it seems to remove playsinline parameter and it must be added via js.