# how to add "webkit-playsinline" to Edge Animate/PhoneGap project?

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, webkit, adobe-edge

This is a much covered subject, however, I am not a coder and have not seen a clear breakdown of how to implement the "webkit-playsinline" tag, particularly in the context of Edge Animate (v.CC 2014.1.1).

I am looking to understand what libraries I may need to import and where to do this, or if I need to initiate something to get the tag to work (some function maybe) - I see there's an additional 'controls' attribute mentioned here: [use webkit-playsinline in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472690/use-webkit-playsinline-in-javascript)

If someone will be kind enough to break this down for an idiot it will be much appreciated.

Using PhoneGap everything is working on Android and iPad, just need to try and get video to work inline and not pop into full-screen on iPhone - and apologies for not just jumping on one of the many other threads, only when you try there's a big notice saying not to do this =]

Thank you.