# Add HTML Attribute without a value using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add an attribute to a HTML element without a value using JQuery

```
<input id="r1" type="radio name="r1" value="1">
```

Add `required`

```
<input id="r1" type="radio name="r1" value="1" required>
```

How can this be done without the `=""`after the attribute?

Comment: don't worry about the `=""`, it's irrelevant just like the missing `/`

Comment: `$('input').attr('required','');`

Comment: @KevinB I believe `<DOCTYPE !html>` would be required, tho.

Comment: why are there two `id` attributes

Comment: it's actually a boolean property and as such not required to have any value. You could add required='fred' and it would work the same. See :http://html5doctor.com/html5-forms-introduction-and-new-attributes/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set attribute without value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159180/set-attribute-without-value)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard practice would be to set the property to `true`

```
$("#r1").prop("required", true);
```

This actually results in markup that exactly reads

```
<input id="r1" required>
```

JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8SrED/

Comment: Afaik setting a property won't set an attribute, especially any custom attribute.

Comment: Not sure if it matter but when I use that I get `required="required"`
**** This was for `$('#r1').attr()` *****

Comment: @teemu, there are lots of prop/attr bindings: title, name, id, rel, draggable, disabled, required, href, src, className/class, and more, just to name some common ones.

Comment: setting the property using .prop sometimes will add an attribute and sometimes won't. It depends on the property and the browser, jQuery isn't doing it.