# How to set a attribute without value or ' ="" ' at end

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem is... i want `<anytag id="blah" class="blahblah" myattrwithoutvalue>`
BUT looking at `console.log($("#blah").html());` i see:

myattrwithoutvalue`=""` - The third-party plugin dont accept it.

`$(selector).attr("attribute")` without value or
`$(selector).attr("attribute",null)` dont insert
any attribute.

How to solve this?

```
var table = "";
table += "<table id='table1'>\n";
table += "</table>\n";
$("#place1").html(table);
$("#table1").addClass("myclass");
$("#table1").attr("mynewattr","");
var ptable = $("#place1").html();
console.log(ptable);
```

Console

```
<table id="table1" class="myclass" mynewattr="">
</table>
```

Html

```
<div id="place1">
</div>
```

Comment: `$("#place1").attr("mynewattr","");` works http://jsfiddle.net/MBwYj/

Comment: There is no difference in the DOM between these notations. Which third party plugin does not like this, which attribute name is it actually and what browser are you using?

Comment: Are you sure that third-party plugin insists on a valueless attribute, or does `mynewattr="mynewattr"` work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159180/set-attribute-without-value

Comment: if you really have the problem - `table += "<table id='table1' mynewattr>\n";`

Comment: @Satpal No, it doesn't, it gives `mynewattr=""`: http://jsfiddle.net/2m69m/

Comment: @AndersAbel Interesting, in the Chrome Dev Tools the attribute does not contain `=""` but in the `.html()` output it does...

Comment: @AndersAbel looks like the `html()` normalizes the innerHTML, here you can see the inline `myattr` is also shown as `myattr=""` http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/2m69m/1/

Comment: What's this third party plugin that you're talking about?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the third-party library to me.  There shouldn't be any difference between those two notations.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all guys. I did contact with the library owner and pointed the problem.
Some hours later He sent an email announcing the new fixed version at github.
I apologize.

Comment: Which one was it? Please link the bugfix at least.