# Create script tag with async attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm injecting a script like so:

```
var script = $('<script>', {
    type: 'text/javascript',
    async: true,
    src: 'https://script.js'
});

$('script:first').before(script);
```

This generates markup like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="async" src="https://script.js"></script>
```

I would prefer the following syntax:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://script.js"></script>
```

Is this supported when passing options to a jQuery DOM element creator? Or, should I just use plain JavaScript to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want the other syntax? The easiest workaround is probably making the whole thing a string instead of an object that jquery converts.

Comment: Partially just curious, but also all other scripts on my page are loaded with requireJS which styles the script using the alternative syntax. It was hard for me to quickly skim all my scripts when one was different.

Comment: Looks like this should work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159180/set-attribute-without-value

Comment: It doesn't generate markup at all. It adds a script element to the DOM.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can set the attribute using plain JS.  Doing it through jQuery will auto-populate the value.

```
var script = $('<script>', {
    type: 'text/javascript',
    src: 'https://script.js'
});

script[0].setAttribute("async", "");

$('script:first').before(script);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from turtle import *
import colorsys

speed(0)
bgcolor("black")
h=0

for i in range(16):
    for j in range(18):
        c=colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(h,0.9,1)
        color(c)
        h+=0.005
        rt(90)
        circle(150-j*6,90)
        lt(90)
        circle(150-j*6,90)
        rt(180)
    circle(40,24)
    
done()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).