# Add ASYNC to <script> tag on when running document.head

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, head, appendchild

I'm trying to *inject* a JavaScript file into `<head></head>`. The JavaScript file is async, and I want to add it to the `script` tag when *injecting*.

This is what I have so far:

```
var imported = document.createElement('script');
imported.src = 'http://domain/js/my.js';
imported.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
imported.async = async;
document.head.appendChild(imported);
```

This injects the JavaScript file, but I get error on line `imported.async = async;`:

> uncaught ReferenceError: async is not defined

And `async` is not added to the tag.

How can I add `async` into that *injected* JavaScript file?

*PS: I'm not looking for a jQuery answer, only pure JavaScript.*

Comment: try imported.async = true

Comment: `async` is not defined in your script.. Either define it or just `imported.async = true;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create script tag with async attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26223193/create-script-tag-with-async-attribute)

Comment: @PriyeshKumar Thanks, `imported.async = true` is correct. Add it as a answer and I can *check* it as correct

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Thats with `jQuery` and I look for a pure `javascript`

Comment: ... It's not that different. The important part in the answers was `async = true`, which would have answered your question. There's also http://stackoverflow.com/q/2774373/215552, among others. Had you searched, it would have been apparent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`async` variable is not defined and so `imported.async = async;` will throw error.

You can do `var async = true; or false` and then `imported.async = async;`

OR

`imported.async = true;`

Note that `async` attribute should be `boolean`.

Read docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Answer (score 0):

I can not comment.. because I don't have the rep. But I wanted to add to the accepted answer, that you could also have done:

```
imported.async = !!async;
```

this would asign false if the value is false or if async is undefined and true only if defined and initialized on true.