# HTML & Javascript change content inside angle brackets ( < > )

Tags: javascript, html, dom, tags

Just wanted to know if it is possible to change with pure Javascript the content between the angle brackets in a HTML tag.
By this I mean all the content, not only the tag name, not only the id, not only  the class and all the different attributes but everything inside, even non standart HTML code.

*One small example:*
*Before*

```
<div id="myID" class="myCLASS" whaterver-content ></div>
```

*After Javascript DOM function*

```
<div id="myID" class="myCLASS" other-content ></div>
```

I know tag name, id and class can be modified with DOM Element Object functions in JS. Is there any nice function that does the same for data not inside quotes and not before an attribute?

Thanks for your answers.

**EDIT:** I just saw this [Set attribute without value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159180/set-attribute-without-value) by asking the question on another way. But is the result the same? Or will there be ="" after the attribute?

Comment: Do you know the string `whaterver-content`? Is it the same to be replaced or does it vary?

Comment: setAttribute? By the way, that would be a good jquery usecase...

Comment: Are you asking about invalid HTML in a string or a DOM that was created from invalid HTML?

Comment: @KobyDouek Yes I know his value and I'd like to replace it by another known value.

Comment: @Jonasw And if i left the value blank, will ="" appear next to the attribute?

Comment: what do you mean by "data not inside quotes and not before an attribute " ?

Comment: @Quentin in th'e example, the div is so by default and I'd like to keep it like this, exwcept changeing the attribute by another.

Comment: @KristjanKica if I use in JS the setAttribute("wathever"," "); will the result be <div wathever></div> or <div wathever=" "></div> ?

Comment: @Ascor8522 — That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not like the accepted answer. You should not be manipulating HTML as string. It is not safe and performance is usually really bad.

Imagine that `whaterver-content` is actual text somewhere inside that div, for example as user input. It will get replaced when it should not be.

Please use DOM manipulation directly:

```
var element = document.getElementById('myID');
element.removeAttribute("whaterver-content");
element.setAttribute("other-content", "");
```

Comment: I also found this solution (look at the edit)... both are working but I agree with you it's maybe best to work with DOM. Btw, as the value of the attribute is blank, will there be ="" after the attribute?

Comment: Short answer: it will work as you expect. Long answer: missing attribute value and empty string attribute are one and the same thing in HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `replace` on the element's `outerHTML` attribute?

```js
function change() {
   document.getElementById('myID').outerHTML = 
       document.getElementById('myID').outerHTML.replace('whaterver-content','other-content');
   console.info(document.getElementById('myID').outerHTML);
}
```

```html
<div id="myID" class="myCLASS" whaterver-content ></div>
<input type='button' onclick='change();' value='change' />
```

Comment: @Ascor8522 What exactly do you want then? Can you specify better?

Comment: In my case, i'd like to change the whole tag, not just getting his "value" or a string of it

Comment: What I wrote changes the whole tag, without changing its value... Isn't that it? Can you give a better example?

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't see that the result was different ^^ I tougth it was just an outerHTML function... By the way, it's exactly what I was expecting ;) Thanks a lot