# Angular - Renderer2 : How to Set Attribute without value?

Tags: angular, angular-renderer2

There is a post on [Set Attribute Without value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159180/set-attribute-without-value/) which provides a good solution using `$('body').attr('data-body','');`

However, in my current ionic project, I am using Angular's Renderer2 API to manipulate DOM, and I have a requirement to create a button dynamically and also to set `ion-button` as one of the attributes.

I am able to set the attributes which are having value with the below code, but not getting any luck in figuring out how to add the attribute without the value.

```
// Make Copy Button functional
   this.renderer.setAttribute(code, 'id', 'copy-target');
   this.renderer.addClass(button, 'copy-button');
   this.renderer.setAttribute(button, 'data-clipboard-action', 'copy');
   this.renderer.setAttribute(button, 'data-clipboard-target', '#copy-target');

   this.renderer.setAttribute(button, 'ion-button', null); // this doesn't work.
```

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: What about  `this.renderer.setAttribute(button, 'ion-button', '');` ?

Comment: `setAttribute` requires `el: any, name: string, value: string, namespace?: string` the null must be a string. perhaps just add an empty string and see if it has the expected behavior `''`.

Comment: Null is a string too though.

Comment: @Grenther I tried 3 options `''`, `null`, and not giving any option at all. Still no luck. When I don't pass 3rd argument it comes as undefined.

Comment: @ritaj technically it's not a string `'Null'` would be a string. Null may be used instead of a string in certain conditions tho.

Comment: @NeerajJain The docs show it should contain a string. AFAIK when you have something like `<button ion-button ...` it should behave the same way as `<button ion-button="" ....` so an empty string should work (could be that I'm wrong tho) Please check if the problem really lies in here

Answer (score 2):

You should just pass an empty string.
I just tried:

```
this.r.setAttribute(this.div.nativeElement, "ion-button", "");
```

On

```
@ViewChild("div") div: ElementRef;
```

And got

```
<div _ngcontent-c0="" ion-button="">Divara</div>
```

Which is the same as

```
<div _ngcontent-c0="" ion-button>Divara</div>
```

Chrome even renders it like that in developer tools:

[image]