# How to set an HTML Element's attribute to null?

Tags: javascript, html

Using `setAttribute(<key>, <value>)` means the null value supplied will be converted to a string, and you end up with `<element <key>="null">`.

I would ideally like the element to appear as `<element <key>>` like `<my-comp show>`, instead of the above or `<my-comp show=''>`

How would I be able to achieve this without modifying `outerHTML` property please?

Comment: Why would `someObject[objectKey] = null;` not work for you?

Comment: Why does the syntax used to express the value of an attribute in a serialisation of a DOM matter?

Comment: I would recommend using `removeAttribute` because some attributes may or may not accept values and still work example `checked` on radio button and checkboxes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set attribute without value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159180/set-attribute-without-value)

Comment: @Quentin It doesn't matter to the DOM. This is out of human readability considerations for debugging ergonomics purposes.

Comment: @Justinas That helped indeed, although that was a jQuery answer. I posted the not jQuery answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edge / Chrome only:**

Set the element attribute to an empty string `''` is sufficient to have the attribute value set to null (tested in Edge/Chromium). This will not lead the element to have a `<attr>=""` in its tag. See example below.

```js
document.getElementById('a').setAttribute('show', '')
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div id='a'>Hi</div>
```

Comment: "*This will not lead the element to have a `<attr>=""` in its tag*" - but (and this may, or may not, be a problem for OP) it *does* result in `<attr>=""` in the DOM in Firefox (this isn't a criticism of the answer, but information for someone wanting the same outcome in future).

Comment: @DavidThomas Thanks for that! Updated to include disclaimer

Answer (score -2):

You can
document.getElementById("xyz").removeAttribute("show");

Comment: The OP is asking how to have a boolean attribute which is present without the `="..."` part. They aren't asking how to remove the attribute.