# Add data attribute to html (depending on screen size)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm looking for the simplest and short method for adding data attribute to html, depending on screen size.

Specific example:
I have some HTML:

```
<nav>...</nav>
```

And I need:

```
<nav data-navigation>... </nav>
```

*when screen width is < 768px

Tried this:

```
    if($(window).width()<768){
    $("nav").setAttribute('data-navigation');
} 
else {
    $("nav").removeAttribute('data-navigation');
}
$(window).resize(function(){
  if($(window).width()<768){
        $("nav").setAttribute('data-navigation');
    } 
    else {
        $("nav").removeAttribute('data-navigation');
    }
});
```

but not working

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please include your attempts. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and its linked resources for more info. Specifically the part about a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159180/set-attribute-without-value

Comment: This seems to be an X/Y question - for what reason would you need to do this? If it's to make some change within the UI then you would be better off using CSS media queries, not updating the attributes of the DOM.

Comment: I'm just need "data-navigation" in nav section ONLY on small screens. Ots not about css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must do it this way then set a [resize event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event) on the window and test for that. I've added a bit of CSS so you can see the result visually. Example below:

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', checkScreenSize);
window.onload = () => {
  checkScreenSize();
}

function checkScreenSize() {
  const nav = document.querySelector('nav');
  if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
    nav.setAttribute('data-navigation', '');
  } else {
    nav.removeAttribute('data-navigation');
  }
}
```

```css
[data-navigation] {
  background-color: goldenrod;
}
```

```html
<nav>This is a nav </nav>
```

Comment: Its working! But only on resizing screen.

Comment: Yes. But when I'm load page in any size - its not working. Only when changing width

Comment: I've edited my answer it so that it also runs when the window is loaded.

Comment: YES! I love you :-*

Comment: Thanks but Valentine's day was a couple of days ago 

Comment: Damn. I screwed up. The solution was correct, but did not give the desired result. I'm trying to use this nav from framework (https://responsivebp.com/javascript/navigation/). But its hiding menu by default overlay window. I thought that displaying the parameter (data-navigation) only on small screens would solve the problem. But not... =(