# How to use JQuery to get data property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

From here [Are empty HTML5 data attributes valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729080/are-empty-html5-data-attributes-valid)

They said that data attribute can be property

So I use this to test, this expected result is true / false, but I only got undefined, how to get the correct result using jquery?

```
<input type='checkbox' onclick='testDataProp(this)' data-tf>
<input type='checkbox' onclick='testDataProp(this)'>
function testDataProp(clickedBox)
{
    var trueFalse=$(clickedBox).prop('data-tf');
    alert(trueFalse);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) to get data attributes, as:

```
function testDataProp(clickedBox)
{
    var trueFalse=$(clickedBox).data('tf');
    alert(trueFalse);
}
```

Demo [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dvA9K/)

**Update:**
you could use [.hasData()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.hasdata/) to check, as:

```
function testDataProp(clickedBox)
{
    var trueFalse=$.hasData(clickedBox); //returns false
    alert(trueFalse);
}
```

**If you want to check if `data-tf` attribute exists then you could use [.hasAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.hasAttribute):**

```
function testDataProp(clickedBox)
{
    var trueFalse=$(clickedBox)[0].hasAttribute('data-tf'); //returns true for first and false for second checkbox
    alert(trueFalse);
}
```

Comment: A boolean attribute in HTML5 should be no value

Comment: @CLSo see the update, do you mean something like that..!

Comment: Not JQuery,  but hasAttribute may be the cloesest answer.