# Remove HTML attribute without a value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, r, shiny

I have an R shiny app with a navbar from the R shiny package. **However, I'm interested in the output HTML so no R specific knowledge is required here.**

Tabbing through this navbar skips entries when those tabs have previously been selected. This is because when a tab is selected shiny adds `class="active"` to the <li> element for that tab in the navbar. When you then click off the tab it takes away the `="active"` and you're left with just `<li class>`. According to [Is an empty class attribute valid HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30748847/is-an-empty-class-attribute-valid-html) this is invalid HTML, and this must be why tabbing through the navbar is broken

I want to remove these class targets without a value. I tried using jquery to do this by adding

```js
$(document).on('hide.bs.tab', (x) => {
    $('*[class!=*]').removeAttr('class');
```

to remove all these targets whenever a new tab is selected. However, I think this is causing some additional mayhem as other features in the app are now broken - to be expected at this is a very brute force approach. The problem is seeing as this HTML is invalid I'm not sure how to properly select it!

If anyone could advise on a strategy to deal with this that'd be great. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, check if [this](https://jsfiddle.net/aenzmjds/) works for you .

Answer (score 0):

Use the attribute `[]` selector for *empty class* like: `[class=""]`

```js
$('[class=""]').removeAttr("class");
```

```css
[class] {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">class="foo"</div>
<div class="">class=""</div>
<div class>class</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In pure JavaScript you would do it like:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[class=""]').forEach(el => el.removeAttribute("class"));
```

```css
[class] {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">class="foo"</div>
<div class="">class=""</div>
<div class>class</div>
```

without the need to load an entire library.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like that

```
 <a class="x" id="myid">btn</a>   
 document.getElementById("myid").removeAttribute('class');
```