# Accessibility : empty alt attribute in thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

It is a good practice to use an empty alt attribute for images that don't need or don't have a text description. This is done by setting an empty alt attribute :

```
<img alt=""...
```

However in thymealf, when using a dynamic alt text that resolves to something null or empty, the attribute is removed altogether :

```
<img th:alt="${media.altText}"...
```

Is there an elegant way to solve this issue ?

Comment: How about the Elvis operator and single quotes for the default value?  `<img th:alt="${media.altText ?: ''}">` . Many ways to do it, adding an empty check if you need it. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20636456/using-thymeleaf-when-the-value-is-null

Comment: The result is the same with an empty string : the attribute is removed.

Comment: Interesting - may have been a design choice to remove the attribute altogether.  Similar discussion in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42935823/creating-empty-data-attributes-in-thymeleaf/42936361

Answer (score 2):

The only option here would probably be something like this:

```
<img th:if="${#strings.isEmpty(media.altText)}" alt="" ... />
<img th:unless="${#strings.isEmpty(media.altText)}" th:alt="${media.altText}" ... />
```

It does mean duplicating your image tags, which may or may not work for you but it should solve the empty alt tag problem.  (You could probably add it to a fragment that you include which would solve the code duplication aspect at least.)

Comment: Agreed, I think this attribute should be changed to work differently at the Thymeleaf level.  I just don't think there is an elegant solution for this...